# How can I set the newline separator for Doctrine-generated code?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, newline, symfony-2.5

I am working on a Symfony 2 project which uses Doctrine. Development is mainly happening on Windows which is why all files have \r\n as newline separator.

However, when adding new properties to my entity classes and then running `app/console doctrine:generate:entities` Doctrine will add the generated code with \n newline separators. This results in files with inconsistent newline separators. The next time I open them my editor/IDE will replace all the \n with \r\n and show all those lines as changed even though the only change was the newline separator.

How can I tell Doctrine that it should respect the newline separators which are already present in the file when generating code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't wont to use unix style newlines? Every IDE can hadle that for you. And there is no problem for windows php implementation to handle unix style newlines.